# How to get an empty array with Prisma2 error when no records found

Tags: prisma

When there are no records in database, Photon (Prisma2) throws an error, instead of returning a null array as in Prisma. What is the best way to treat this, getting an empty array when no records found? I didn't want all my Photon queries surrounded by try and catch statements.

For example:

```
photon.context.photon.users.findOne({ where: { email } })
```

Gives the error:

> Error in connector: Record does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug according to [this](https://github.com/prisma/photonjs/issues/89) and [this](https://github.com/prisma/photonjs/issues/136) issues on github. However, using `findMany` instead of `findOne` might solve your problem